# How to plot a histogram for each sample from a 2D-array

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

On a dataset, I fitted one machine learning model multiples time and I collected the predictions in a NumPy array. The shape of the NumPy array is `(400, 250)` where `250` is the number of times I fitted the model and `400` is the number of the test samples.

Now, I wanted to see the histogram for each sample's prediction. In a more elegant way, I want to see the histogram of how the prediction differs one from another.

I am trying the below code

```
plt.hist(rep_predictions.T, orientation='horizontal', bins=10)
plt.xlabel("Samples")
plt.ylabel(f"Predicted Value of the LinReg model")
plt.title(f"All Predicted vs Samples")
```

I am getting the below figure (though it does not fulfill my expectation)

[image: histogram fig]

Is it feasible to see the histogram of each sample's multiple predictions? My expectation is, there will be samples on the x-axis, and the prediction value will be on the y-axis.